# How To Handle Multiple Actions in Expo React Native Local Notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, react-native-push-notification, expo-notifications

it could be a silly question, I don't have much experience in Expo React Native, I want to create multiple actions with a single notification,
if the user clicks on the title user should redirect to a single profile page
and if the user clicks on the chat button user should redirect to the chat screen.
is this functionality possible with **Expo Notifications**

i tried

```
scheduleNotificationAsync
```

[image]

but still didn't get any success.